# PHP won't echo?

Tags: php

When I do:

`php -r "echo 'Hello, world.'";`

Nothing shows up.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04. I've done `sudo apt-get install php5-cli`.

What is up?

Comment: You mean aside from the typo?

Comment: You're not telling us everything - there is an error message that gets emitted.

Comment: I am all but certain that your problems comes from the semicolon being outside the quotes, stop wasting the forum's time.

Comment: How is it wasting the forum's time when I found a solution to my problem?

Comment: @Eamorr: You didn't tell us what the error message was, this doesn't relate to server administration and is generally crappy, that's how you wasted our time.

Comment: There was no error message on the console. You speak only for yourself; not the forum. You don't have a monopoly on what does and doesn't constitute time-wasting. Hopefully this question will be of use to someone in future.

Comment: @Eamorr This is a poor question at best -  You're coming to us saying "It's Broken!" but you're not giving us any real usable detail. [Please check here for some tips](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault).

Comment: @Eamorr Also while I don't doubt your assertion that "nothing shows up" you should generally ensure that PHP's [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) is turned on when trying to debug things. (Copying and pasting exactly what you have above, an error message is most certainly displayed [*if PHP is configured to do so*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting the semicolon inside the statement. So `php -r "echo 'Hello, world.';"`